# Error adding Azure DevOps Connector on Microsoft Teams related to Browser being used by Teams

Tags: azure-devops, office365, microsoft-teams

I am running Windows 10, with IE Edge browser as my default. When I try to add the Azure DevOps Connector to the Team channel, the app asks me to first signin to AzureDevOps; the login prompt appears in a browser embedded within the app which I assumed to be the edge browser itself. However, the authentication seems to be passing but probably the token is not being received. Even the message that says I should be using Edge is misleading. My system default is Edge browser and authentication via the browser works fine but not via the App. I have not seen any settings in the App that allows me to choose a browser explicitly. Appreciate if someone could please help me with any headway as to what I am missing on this ? Have seen many JSON config files in the teams working directory but not sure if something needs to be changed there. Not particularly sure, if this has something to do with my organization policy since if I choose to add the inbuilt Azure Boards ***Tab*** (or pipelines etc.) then the same authentication etc. is being done automatically without the pop up that appears when I choose the ***Connector*** option.

Please see this image : [Error with app browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcARf.jpg)

Trouble shooting details provided in the snapshot :

Request Id: Some ID
Correlation Id: Some correlation ID
Timestamp: 2021-04-29T06:19:36.811Z
App name: Azure DevOps
App id: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
Device platform: Windows 10

Comment: So it turns out that a workaround to do this is to Have Chrome installed and then add the Windows 10 extension. Then open teams using the browser, add the connector, set the configurations and voila!!! the Desktop App now has the connector as well. Strange, but some reasoning would help to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that a workaround to do this is to Have Chrome installed and then add the Windows 10 extension. Then open teams using the browser, add the connector, set the configurations and voila!!! the Desktop App now has the connector as well. Strange, but some reasoning would help to understand this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues, thank you very much.